# ORDER BY Color with Hex Code as a criterio in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, similarity

I have a table that contains color options for a product. The color options include a hex color code, which is used to generate the UI (HTML).

I would like to sort the rows so that the colors in the UI look like a rainbow, instead of the current order that sorts based off of the Name of the color (not very useful).

Here is what my query looks like. I get the R G B decimal values from the hex code. I just don't know how to order it.

I've looked into color difference algorithms. They seem more useful to compare 2 colors' similarity, not sort.

I'm using MySQL:

```
select a.*, (a.c_r + a.c_g + a.c_b) color_sum
from (
    select co.customization_option_id, 
            co.designer_image_url,  
            concat(co.name, " (",cog.name, ")") name, 
            co.customization_option_group_id gr, 
            designer_hex_color,
            conv(substr(designer_hex_color, 1, 2), 16, 10) c_r,
            conv(substr(designer_hex_color, 3, 2), 16, 10) c_g,
            conv(substr(designer_hex_color, 5, 2), 16, 10) c_b
    from customization_options co 
            left join customization_option_groups cog 
            on cog.id = co.customization_option_group_id 
    where co.customization_id = 155 
            and co.customization_option_group_id 
            in (1,2,3,4)) a
order by ????
```

Comment: Possible diuplicate of - check out this SO question 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239986/convert-rgb-to-light-frequency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort hex codes by wavelength, this roughly maps onto the hue-value. Given a hexcode as a six character string: `RRGGBB`.

You just need to make a function that takes in a hexcode string and outputs the hue value, here's the formula [from this Math.SO answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556341/rgb-to-hsv-color-conversion-algorithm):

R' = R/255

G' = G/255

B' = B/255

Cmax = max(R', G', B')

Cmin = min(R', G', B')

Δ = Cmax - Cmin

[image: hue calculation given RGB values]

I wanted to see if this would work, so I whipped up a sample program in Ruby, it samples 200 random colors uniformly from RGB-space, and sorts them, the output looks like a rainbow!

Here's the Ruby source:

```
require 'paint'

def hex_to_rgb(hex)
  /(?<r>..)(?<g>..)(?<b>..)/ =~ hex
  [r,g,b].map {|cs| cs.to_i(16) }
end

def rgb_to_hue(r,g,b)
  # normalize r, g and b
  r_ = r / 255.0
  g_ = g / 255.0
  b_ = b / 255.0

  c_min = [r_,g_,b_].min
  c_max = [r_,g_,b_].max

  delta = (c_max - c_min).to_f

  # compute hue
  hue = 60 * ((g_ - b_)/delta % 6) if c_max == r_
  hue = 60 * ((b_ - r_)/delta + 2) if c_max == g_
  hue = 60 * ((r_ - g_)/delta + 4) if c_max == b_

  return hue
end

# sample uniformly at random from RGB space
colors = 200.times.map {  (0..255).to_a.sample(3).map { |i| i.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0')}.join   }

# sort by hue
colors.sort_by { |color| rgb_to_hue(*hex_to_rgb(color)) }.each do |color|
  puts Paint[color, color]
end
```

Note, make sure to `gem install paint` to get the colored text output.

Here's the output:

[image: zoomed out colorized output]

It should be relatively straight-forward to write this as a SQL user-defined function and ORDER BY RGB_to_HUE(hex_color_code), however, my SQL knowledge is pretty basic.

EDIT: I posted [this question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/64264/5595) about converting the Ruby to a SQL user defined function.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the [answer by @dliff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397594/sql-order-by-color-hex-code/23620824#23620824). I initially edited it, but it turns out my edit [was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14009328) saying "*it should have been written as a comment or an answer*". Seeing this would be too large to post as a comment, here goes.

The reason for editing (and now posting) is this: there seems to be a problem with colors like 808080 because their R, G and B channels are equal. If one needs this to sort or group colors and keep the passed grayscale/non-colors separate, that answer won't work, so I edited it.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `hex_to_hue`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `hex_to_hue`(HEX VARCHAR(6)) RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
    DECLARE r FLOAT;
    DECLARE b FLOAT;
    DECLARE g FLOAT;
    DECLARE MIN FLOAT;
    DECLARE MAX FLOAT;
    DECLARE delta FLOAT;
    DECLARE hue FLOAT;
    IF(HEX = '') THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    SET r = CONV(SUBSTR(HEX, 1, 2), 16, 10)/255.0;
    SET g = CONV(SUBSTR(HEX, 3, 2), 16, 10)/255.0;
    SET b = CONV(SUBSTR(HEX, 5, 2), 16, 10)/255.0;
    SET MAX = GREATEST(r,g,b);
    SET MIN = LEAST(r,g,b);
    SET delta = MAX - MIN;
    SET hue=
    (CASE 
        WHEN MAX=r THEN (60 * ((g - b)/delta % 6))
        WHEN MAX=g THEN (60 * ((b - r)/delta + 2))
        WHEN MAX=b THEN (60 * ((r - g)/delta + 4))
        ELSE NULL
    END);
    IF(ISNULL(hue)) THEN
        SET hue=999;
    END IF;
    RETURN hue;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Again, I initially wanted to edit the original answer, not post as a separate one.

Answer (score 0):

If your products can have lots of color probably a good UI will require a color picker, normally those are rectangular, so not really something possible with the order by.

If the products have a manageable number of colors you have different choice, the easiest to implement is an order table, where for every possible color is defined an order position, this table can then be joined to your query, something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM   (SELECT ... 
               ...
               ...
             , ci.color_order
        FROM   customization_options co 
               LEFT JOIN customization_option_groups cog 
                         ON cog.id = co.customization_option_group_id
               LEFT JOIN color_ ci
                         ON designer_hex_color = ci.color
        WHERE  ...) a
ORDER BY color_order
```

Another way to go is to transform the RGB color to hue and use this as the order.
There are different formula for this conversion, depending on wich order you want the primary color to have, all of them can be found on the wikipedia page for [hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue), I can update the answer to help you convert one of those to T-SQL, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL function Hex to Hue. Based on Tobi's answer. :)

```
CREATE FUNCTION `hex_to_hue`(hex varchar(6)) RETURNS float
BEGIN
declare r float;
declare b float;
declare g float;
declare min float;
declare max float;
declare delta float;
declare hue float;

set r = conv(substr(hex, 1, 2), 16, 10)/255.0;
set g = conv(substr(hex, 3, 2), 16, 10)/255.0;
set b = conv(substr(hex, 5, 2), 16, 10)/255.0;

set max = greatest(r,g,b);
set min = least(r,g,b);

set delta = max - min;

set hue=
(case 
    when max=r then (60 * ((g - b)/delta % 6))
    when max=g then (60 * ((b - r)/delta + 2))
    when max=b then (60 * ((r - g)/delta + 4))
    else null
end);

RETURN hue;
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! You got my upvote, but there seems to be a problem with colors like `808080` because their R, G and B channels are equal. If one need this to sort colors *and* keep the passed non-colors separate, that won't work, so I edited this a little bit