# How the hexadecimal color code transfer to wave length?

Tags: javascript

How or where can I generate the wavelength value from the hexadecimal color code?

(Yes, there are for instance useful pages such as https://encycolorpedia.com/ where this information is available. But some colors exhibit wrong data, e.g. black #000000 cannot be 477.19 nm, or purple hues have also dubious wavelength values.)

Comment: Why should “black” have any wavelength? Black is the absence of light.

Comment: @misorude I think that's OP's point: 477.19 nm is clearly wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert RGB to light frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239986/convert-rgb-to-light-frequency)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [convert RGB pixel to wavelength](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35481345/1220550)