# Sort Colour / Color Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, colors, alignment

Im looking to align the following array of colours as precisely as possible.

After searching & trying many solutions suggested on Stackoverflow, the pusher.color library has the best solution, however, it too is far from perfect. I would like to hear solutions on how we can align them perfectly.

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/dxux7y3e/) : http://jsfiddle.net/dxux7y3e/

Code:

```
var coloursArray=['#FFE9E9','#B85958','#FFB1AE','#FFC2BF','#C55E58','#FFC7C4','#FF9A94','#FF9D96','#FA9790','#A78B88','#A78B88','#CE675B','#DB8073','#FF9D90','#FF7361','#FFD6D1','#F9A092','#FF7B67','#EBACA2','#FF806D','#DD6D5B','#D16654','#ED8673','#FFC4B8','#E2725B','#ED7A64','#8F3926','#BD492F','#9D3C27','#AD533E','#BF4024','#FFC9BC','#6B6766','#E1CDC8','#C2654C','#B3978F','#FFC7B8','#CE2B00','#C2654C','#A24D34','#FF926D','#E78667','#FFB198','#8C756D','#9E6D5B','#FFC7B0','#FFBEA4','#D2B9AF','#FFB193','#632710','#B26746','#976854','#F44900','#E79873','#EFA27F','#532510','#BC866B','#FDE5D9','#FF5B00','#D18C67','#FF5B00','#9E4312','#763713','#BB6B39','#B5622E','#CC7742','#6D4227','#B56B38','#FF7518','#F3B080','#995C30','#995C30','#FF6A00','#D89769','#71472A','#EDAC7B','#EEAB79','#EBCFB9','#FBE3D1','#E19255','#5E381B','#FFDCC1','#FFF0E4','#F68D39','#7B5B40','#FF8313','#FFCEA4','#AA8667','#975414','#CB9867','#8C5B2B','#FFCE9E','#7B4714','#FFF3E7','#FFA449','#CEAF90','#CDB69E','#EFD6BC','#DDA66B','#B27737','#B88A57','#CE9B61','#F4C38B','#543817','#BC9C78','#DBB07A','#FF8E04','#F6EADB','#DBC2A4','#C49B64','#CBA26B','#80551E','#FF9200','#FFECD3','#FFC87C','#FFB755','#DBB680','#D2D0CD','#EFDBBE','#E5C18B','#FFE5BC','#F2EADB','#885F12','#FFE7B6','#825A08','#906712','#F2D18E','#C8C6C2','#FFB000','#FFC243','#C6BEAD','#D0C3A4','#916800','#8C6700','#F4E9CA','#FFF0C5','#FFE080','#FFEBA8','#846600','#FFE692','#F5F0DB','#433F2F','#BBB394','#FFEFAA','#FFE76D','#FFFAE0','#3E3B28','#554900','#E1E0D8','#74725C','#605F54','#F8F7DD','#A5A467','#DDDDDA','#FFFFEE','#A3A39D','#E0E0D7','#BEBEB9','#E8E8E5','#454531','#ACACAA','#E9E9DF','#FFFFDC','#EBEBE7','#979831','#C5C6BE','#B9C866','#898D72','#F3FAD1','#616452','#CED5B0','#A1A787','#595C4E','#B0BB8C','#EEFFB6','#ACB78E','#8FA359','#858F6C','#86916E','#374912','#AEB0AA','#79904C','#627739','#747F60','#9FA98E','#E7F9CB','#E1F9BE','#495637','#8A9978','#4E5F39','#86996E','#C3CEB7','#78866B','#CEDDC1','#B5CEA2','#536149','#D6E6CC','#D6E6CC','#809873','#4F564C','#4F6C45','#555F52','#4F7942','#5F705B','#D0DFCD','#2B3929','#F0F7EF','#AAD5A4','#99BC95','#B6D4B4','#869E86','#618661','#006700','#E9EEE9','#739E73','#005B06','#EDF7EE','#D0E0D2','#809784','#ABCEB1','#C0E0C8','#3A5241','#435549','#E6ECE8','#E3EAE6','#3B604C','#00602F','#92B7A5','#2F5B49','#318061','#30745B','#316955','#00A275','#C2D1CE','#80A7A0','#00A082','#C2D1CF','#5C6E6C','#607473','#EDF7F7','#1E8285','#D5E7E8','#AADEE1','#188086','#107F87','#566364','#007B86','#66949A','#CAE2E5','#18656F','#004F61','#0C5B6C','#668E98','#BBD0DA','#91B4C5','#AFC3CD','#738A99','#3A5467','#476174','#244967','#556C80','#667A8C','#516D87','#1E4263','#7C8791','#849CB6','#738CAA','#1E3A5F','#1E3655','#9EB0CE','#B6BAC2','#67738D','#BEC1CD','#555559','#616180','#000049','#000031','#F8F8FC','#938BA4','#47375D','#F7F6F8','#3D0067','#514C53','#9566A2','#7F5482','#A279A4','#6D1261','#A06492','#925582','#945B80','#CE94BA','#ECCFE1','#A20058','#A6005B','#BC0061','#BB0061','#F3CEE1','#B3005B','#AB165F','#8A184D','#AA185B','#F3DAE4','#DB3779','#E71261','#E74F86','#FFD6E5','#BE9BA7','#D0396A','#DB1855','#F798B6','#9C294A','#D62B5B','#DE3969','#BC1641','#E7547A','#D52756','#9C7D85','#DB244F','#A1354F','#C22443','#FFBDCA','#8B6D73','#DC3D5B','#FF738C','#F13154','#BC4055','#FED4DB','#FFCFD6','#CB4E61','#ED455A','#F36C7B','#C94F5B','#F3959D','#A8444C','#FFCCD0','#735B5D','#D15D67','#B44B52','#FD868D','#FFD5D8','#C3767B','#FF8087','#C8242B','#FFEAEB','#F95A61','#E96D73','#E6656B','#FF6D73','#FF555B','#A35A5B','#FFD3D4','#B84B4D'];
        var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

        function hexToRgb(hex) {
            hex = hex.substring(1, hex.length);
            var r = parseInt((hex).substring(0, 2), 16);
            var g = parseInt((hex).substring(2, 4), 16);
            var b = parseInt((hex).substring(4, 6), 16);

            return r + "," + g + "," + b;
        }

        function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
            return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
        }

        var rgbArr=new Array();
        var div=document.createElement('div');
        div.id='Original';

        body.appendChild(div);
        for(var color in coloursArray){
            color=coloursArray[color];
            displayColor(color,div); 
            rgbArr.push(hexToRgb(color));
        }

        var hslArr=new Array();
        for(var i=0;i<rgbArr.length;i++){
            //Transforming rgb to hsl
            //`hslArr[i][1]` (`i`) is a reference to the rgb color, in order to retrieve it later
            hslArr[i]=[rgbToHsl(rgbArr[i]),i]; 
        }
        var sortedHslArr=new Array();
        //Sorting `hslArr` into `sortedHslArr`
        outerloop:
            for(var i=0;i<hslArr.length;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<sortedHslArr.length;j++){
                if(sortedHslArr[j][0][0]>hslArr[i][0][0]){
                    sortedHslArr.splice(j,0,hslArr[i]);
                    continue outerloop;
                }
            }
            sortedHslArr.push(hslArr[i]);
        }
        var sortedRgbArr=new Array();
        //Retrieving rgb colors
        for(var i=0;i<sortedHslArr.length;i++){
            sortedRgbArr[i]=rgbArr[sortedHslArr[i][1]];
        }

        function displayColor(color,parent){
            var div;

            div=document.createElement('div');
            div.style.backgroundColor=color;
            div.style.width='22px';
            div.style.height='22px';
            div.style.cssFloat='left';
            div.style.position='relative';
            parent.appendChild(div);
        }

        var finalArray=new Array();
        var div=document.createElement('div');
        div.id='Sorted';
        body.appendChild(div);
        for(var color in sortedRgbArr){
            color=sortedRgbArr[color];
            color=color.split(',');
            color=rgbToHex(parseInt(color[0]),parseInt(color[1]),parseInt(color[2]));                
            displayColor(color,div);                
            finalArray.push(color);
        }

        function rgbToHsl(c){
            var r = c[0]/255, g = c[1]/255, b = c[2]/255;
            var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
            var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

            if(max == min){
                h = s = 0; // achromatic
            }else{
                var d = max - min;
                s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
                switch(max){
                    case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
                    case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
                    case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
                }
                h /= 6;
            }
            return new Array(h * 360, s * 100, l * 100);
        } 

        var sorted = coloursArray.sort(function(colorA, colorB) {
            return pusher.color(colorA).hue() - pusher.color(colorB).hue();
        });
      //  console.log(sorted);

        var div=document.createElement('div');
        div.id='Pusher';
        body.appendChild(div);
        for(var color in sorted){
            color=sorted[color];                               
            displayColor(color,div);    
        }            

        var div=document.createElement('div');            
        body.appendChild(div);
        var str='';
        for(var color in sorted){
            color=sorted[color];                              
            str+='\''+color+'\',';
        } 
        div.innerHTML=str;


        function sorthueColors (colors) {
            for (var c = 0; c < colors.length; c++) {
                /* Get the hex value without hash symbol. */
                var hex = colors[c].substring(1);
                //var hex = colors[c].hex.substring(1);

                /* Get the RGB values to calculate the Hue. */
                var r = parseInt(hex.substring(0,2),16)/255;
                var g = parseInt(hex.substring(2,4),16)/255;
                var b = parseInt(hex.substring(4,6),16)/255;

                /* Getting the Max and Min values for Chroma. */
                var max = Math.max.apply(Math, [r,g,b]);
                var min = Math.min.apply(Math, [r,g,b]);

                /* Variables for HSV value of hex color. */
                var chr = max-min;
                var hue = 0;
                var val = max;
                var sat = 0;

                if (val > 0) {
                    /* Calculate Saturation only if Value isn't 0. */
                    sat = chr/val;
                    if (sat > 0) {
                        if (r == max) { 
                            hue = 60*(((g-min)-(b-min))/chr);
                            if (hue < 0) {hue += 360;}
                        } else if (g == max) { 
                            hue = 120+60*(((b-min)-(r-min))/chr); 
                        } else if (b == max) { 
                            hue = 240+60*(((r-min)-(g-min))/chr); 
                        }
                    }
                }

                /* Modifies existing objects by adding HSV values. */
                colors[c].hue = hue;
                colors[c].sat = sat;
                colors[c].val = val;
            }

            /* Sort by Hue. */
            return colors.sort(function(a,b){return a.hue - b.hue;});
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - Sort rgb values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923659/javascript-sort-rgb-values)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Problem is, sorting requires a well-defined order - in other words, you need to map all colors to one dimension. While there are some approaches to display the color space in two dimensions, I am not aware of any that would display it in one dimension and still make sense to the human eye.

However, if you don't insist on some universal ordering and you merely want to place a given list of colors in a way that looks nice, then some clustering approach might produce better results. I tried the naive approach, the idea here is to put similar colors into the same cluster and to merge these clusters until you only have one. Here is the code I've got:

```
function colorDistance(color1, color2) {
    // This is actually the square of the distance but
    // this doesn't matter for sorting.
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < color1.length; i++)
        result += (color1[i] - color2[i]) * (color1[i] - color2[i]);
    return result;
}

function sortColors(colors) {
    // Calculate distance between each color
    var distances = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        distances[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
            distances.push([colors[i], colors[j], colorDistance(colors[i], colors[j])]);
    }
    distances.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[2] - b[2];
    });

    // Put each color into separate cluster initially
    var colorToCluster = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++)
        colorToCluster[colors[i]] = [colors[i]];

    // Merge clusters, starting with lowest distances
    var lastCluster;
    for (var i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
        var color1 = distances[i][0];
        var color2 = distances[i][1];
        var cluster1 = colorToCluster[color1];
        var cluster2 = colorToCluster[color2];
        if (!cluster1 || !cluster2 || cluster1 == cluster2)
            continue;

        // Make sure color1 is at the end of its cluster and
        // color2 at the beginning.
        if (color1 != cluster1[cluster1.length - 1])
            cluster1.reverse();
        if (color2 != cluster2[0])
            cluster2.reverse();

        // Merge cluster2 into cluster1
        cluster1.push.apply(cluster1, cluster2);
        delete colorToCluster[color1];
        delete colorToCluster[color2];
        colorToCluster[cluster1[0]] = cluster1;
        colorToCluster[cluster1[cluster1.length - 1]] = cluster1;
        lastCluster = cluster1;
    }

    // By now all colors should be in one cluster
    return lastCluster;
}
```

[Complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ef51xk3y/)

The `colorDistance()` function works with RGB colors that are expressed as arrays with three elements. There are certainly [much better approaches to do this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) and they might produce results that look better. Note also that this isn't the most efficient algorithm because it calculates the distance between each and every color (O(n<sup>2</sup>)) so if you have lots of colors you might want to optimize it.

Comment: thank you for the effort, however, while it certainly seems to align the colour values based on lightness, the hues are all over the place & would cause a lot of grief. I think HSL or HSV is the way to go with these if I can figure out a link between when to jump from one hue to another...

Comment: @Kayote: Feel free to implement a `colorDistance()` function that matches your criteria better - you didn't specify these criteria in the question, and my mind reading skills are a bit rusty. The rest of the algorithm shouldn't need any changes, no matter what comparison function you choose.

Comment: Wanted to mention +1 for demo.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming there is no <kbd>best</kbd> solution. Here is how i would find what i like the most.

First i would use color distance function:

```
var balance = [10, 0, 0.01];
function colorDistance(color1, color2) {
    var result = 0;
    color1 = rgbToHsl(color1[0], color1[1], color1[2]);
    color2 = rgbToHsl(color2[0], color2[1], color2[2]);
    for (var i = 0; i < color1.length; i++)
        result += (color1[i] - color2[i]) * (color1[i] - color2[i]) * balance[i];
    return result;
}
```

I would use balance function :

- **hue distance** `var balance = [1, 0, 0];`
  [image]
- **saturation distance** `var balance = [0, 1, 0];`
  [image]
- `lightness distance` var balance = [0, 0, 1];
  [image]

After that you can just experiment and pick what you like. Note that values are not normalized to appear between **0 to 1** but other then that it should work well. You can also you another distance function this is just most trivial and well known one that gets decent results.

This approach does not give you the best solution, but describes a way to fiddle with it and get result you where looking for. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Hue of a color is usually a pleasant way to map the color on a one-dimensional scale. You could convert the rgb color to hsv using the answers here: [RGB to HSV color in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022885/rgb-to-hsv-color-in-javascript)

Comment: The code in the question appears to be a very convoluted way of doing exactly what you are proposing. The result looks wrong however, my guess would be that the custom sorting algorithm implemented there is buggy.

Answer (score -3):

```
This is an improved code based on pusher.color lib.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kt1zv6g4/3/